# What is the relation between Rancher environment and K8S cluster? Rancher host and K8S node?

Tags: kubernetes, rancher

- Rancher uses [environments](https://rancher.com/docs/rancher/v1.6/en/environments/) as the most coarse-grained element for configuration.
- We typically configure dev and prod *environments*.
- Hosts (physical or virtual) are added to environments.
- Rancher has [templates](https://rancher.com/docs/rancher/v1.6/en/environments/#what-is-an-environment-template) for environments. One of the templates is for creating an environment with Kubernetes orchestration.
- K8S has clusters with nodes. Apparently, when you create a Rancher environment following the K8S template, you establish a K8S cluster.

Questions I could not answer clearly looking at the documentation:

1. *Is the Rancher environment and the K8S cluster the same thing?* (For an environment that uses K8S.)  Or can an environment contain more than one cluster?
2. *Is the Rancher host and the K8S node the same thing?* (Again, for an environment that uses K8S.)

Answer (score 1):

An environment contains a set of machines (hosts/nodes), an orchestration engine (kubernetes being one of the 4 options), and a set of members with different roles defining access to them.  You cannot have more than one kubernetes cluster in one environment.

Yes, the kubernetes term is node.

If you want kubernetes you should really be using Rancher 2.x instead of 1.x.  1.x is in maintenance-only mode and  support will eventually be dropped.  2.x is entirely based around kubernetes and is far better integrated with it.